# Real name on network profile

Tags: support, profile-page

I just noticed a link to my "network profile". How can I choose which name is used for it? I'm using my full name on some SE sites and only the first name on others, and would not like my network profile to display my full name.

Comment: Related on meta.SU - [Question migrated to other stackexchange site displays full name](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/2340/question-migrated-to-other-stackexchange-site-displays-full-name).